# Can't invoke class window

Tags: c#

I'm trying to invoke from my application class

```
using Jade;

namespace Jade
{
    public class Application
    {
        private bool m_Running = true;
        public Application()
        {
            window.CreateWindow();
        }

        ~Application() { }

        public void Run()
        {
            while (m_Running)
            {
                window.OnUpdate();
            }
        }

        private Window window;

        public Application CreateApplication()
        {
            return new Sandbox();
        }
    }
}
```

using my Window class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jade
{
    public struct WindowProps
    {
        public string Title;
        public uint Width;
        public uint Height;

        public WindowProps(in string title = "Camellia Engine", uint width = 1280, uint height = 720)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
        }

    }

    public abstract class Window
    {
        public delegate void EventCallbackFn(Event e);
        ~Window() { }
        public abstract void OnUpdate();
        public abstract uint GetWidth();
        public abstract uint GetHeight();
        public abstract void SetEventCallback(in EventCallbackFn callback);
        public abstract void SetVSync(bool enabled = false);
        public abstract bool IsVSyncEnabled();

        public abstract Window Create(WindowProps props = new WindowProps());

        public void CreateWindow()
        {
            Create();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when running using the Visual Studio debugger, I receive a System.NullReferenceException

I tried making a

```
new Window();
```

but got a CS0144 error: *"Can't create instance from interface or abstract type 'Window'"*

Also tried to make CreateWindow() a static class with

```
public static void CreateWindow()
{
    Create();
}
```

but received a CS0120 error with that try.

I expected to get a GLFW window with this extra code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GLFW;
using GLFW.Game;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Jade
{
    internal class WindowsWindow : Window
    {
        public static bool m_isGLFWInitialized = false;
        public WindowsWindow(WindowProps props) {
            Init(props);
        }
        ~WindowsWindow()
        {
            Shutdown();
        }

        public override void OnUpdate()
        {
            Glfw.PollEvents();
            Glfw.SwapBuffers(m_window);
        }

        public override uint GetWidth()
        {
            return (uint)m_Data.Width;
        }

        public override uint GetHeight()
        {
            return (uint)m_Data.Height;
        }

        public override void SetEventCallback(in EventCallbackFn callback)
        {
            m_Data.EventCallback = callback;
        }

        public override void SetVSync(bool enabled)
        {
            if (enabled)
            {
                Glfw.SwapInterval(1);
            } else
            {
                Glfw.SwapInterval(0);
            }

            m_Data.VSync = enabled;
        }

        public override bool IsVSyncEnabled()
        {
            return m_Data.VSync;
        }
        
        public void Init(in WindowProps props)
        {
            m_Data.Title = props.Title;
            m_Data.Width = props.Width;
            m_Data.Height = props.Height;

            Log.CM_CORE_INFO("Creating window with parameters " + props.Title + " " + props.Width + "x" + props.Height );

            if (!m_isGLFWInitialized)
            {
                bool success = Glfw.Init();

                m_isGLFWInitialized = true;
            }

            m_window = new GameWindow((int)props.Width, (int)props.Height, m_Data.Title);
            GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(m_Data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr dataPtr = (IntPtr)gcHandle;


            Glfw.MakeContextCurrent(m_window);
            Glfw.SetWindowUserPointer(m_window, dataPtr);
            SetVSync(true);

            gcHandle.Free();
        }

        public override Window Create(WindowProps props = default)
        {
            return new WindowsWindow(props);
        }

        public void Shutdown() 
        {
            Glfw.DestroyWindow(m_window);
        }

        private NativeWindow m_window;

        private struct WindowData
        {
            public string Title;
            public uint Width, Height;
            public bool VSync;

            public EventCallbackFn EventCallback;
        };


        WindowData m_Data;


    }
}
```

Could somebody solve my problem?

Comment: `new WindowsWindow()`, not `new Window()` - you cannot instantiate an abstract class. Window is an abstract class. WindowsWindow inherits from Window, and is concrete.

Comment: While we're at it, delete `~Application() { }` and `~Window() {}`, and turn `~WindowsWindow()` into a  `Dispose()` implementation. Finalizers are a bad idea. This isn't C++.